Absolute purity in p-adic case
Suppose that $X$ is a regular proper scheme over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ with smooth generic fiber $X_{\eta}$ and singular special fiber $X_s$. I want to understand $H_{\textrm{et}}^*(X_{\eta},\mathbb{Z}/2)$. What are the possible ways to compute that? Is that possible to start with $H_{\textrm{et}}^*(X_s,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ (no purity theorem here)?
